# template content won't show in opencart

Tags: php, opencart, journal

I'm having an issue with open cart(v2.0.3.1) and the journal template (v2.4.9).

The issue: when I add a journal module like the Carousel, Banners etc. and try to place the module in the content section (either column_right, column_left or content_top, content_bottom) it won't show up on the site (not only home but all other pages aswell) However if I cange the position to "top" or "bottom" it does show up!

I've checked the file **catalog/view/theme/journal2/template/common/home.tpl**
to check if the columns are printed and saw this:

```
<div id="container" class="container j-container"><div class="row"><?php echo $column_left; ?> <?php echo $column_right; ?>
<?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { ?>
<?php $class = 'col-sm-6'; ?>
<?php } elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { ?>
<?php $class = 'col-sm-9'; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php $class = 'col-sm-12'; ?>
<?php } ?>
<div id="content" class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $content_top; ?><?php echo $content_bottom; ?></div>
</div>
```

So they seem to be echoed however they don't show up on the website. 
Actualy they do show up but only with the opencart elements not the custom elements made by the template. 
I could use some help because i've been searching for 2 whole days and I can't seem to find a propper solution. 
Need to figure this out for a client.

Comment: have you contact theme author support for this issue?

Comment: In a way, I personally don't own the license so I contacted my client (he has the license) and he made contact with the author. After an update (to 2.5.4) the problem was resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the template after I updated it to a newer version the issue resolved!